# Let user choose where to save a file my extension provides

Tags: jquery, html, file, directory

My team is working on a google chrome extension that needs to save a file to the users hard drive in order to work.

Now i'm looking for a way to let the user choose where the file is going to be saved and i would like to achieve this by using a similar function like the

"<" input type="file" ">"

method to let the user choose a file to upload, but in my case we want the user to choose a folder where the file is going to be saved.

Is there a way to make this work?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['filename'])) $fn = $_GET['filename'];
$uploader->SaveDirectory= "folder/".$filename."/";
```

get the extension

[PHPUPLOADER](http://phpfileuploader.com/)